# Disable post thumbnails in Twenty Thirteen child theme

Tags: post-thumbnails, theme-twenty-thirteen

I've made a theme that's a child of the standard Twenty Thirteen theme. Twenty Thirteen displays `post_thumbnail` images at the top of each of my pages, and I'd like my theme to not do this.

I could create my own version of all the templates that use it (like `page.php`, `content.php`) but this seems overkill for making such a small change.

I tried doing `remove_theme_suport('post-thumbnail')` but that had no effect.

I tried just deleting the `add_theme_support('post-thumbnail')` line from Twenty Thirteen's `functions.php`, but that had no effect.

I could hide the thumbnail using CSS, but the image is still loaded, and I'd prefer the HTML to not be included at all.

I don't want to go through loads of existing posts/pages and remove all the thumbnails I set ages ago.

Any thoughts? Is it possible to override `has_post_thumbnail()` so that it always returns `FALSE`?

NOTE: This is not the same as the "header" images Twenty Thirteen puts in the site-header block, but appears below the main navigation, in the main content of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How can we force `has_post_thumbnails()` to return `false`?

## Method #1 - disable theme support:

You can remove the post thumbnails support from the backend, with

```
function twentythirteen_child_setup()
{
    remove_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twentythirteen_child_setup', 11 );
```

but notice that this will not remove the featured images.

If the `_thumbnail_id` post meta value is non-empty, then `has_post_thumbnails()` will return `true`. So we need something else, in the that case.

## Method #2 - a script to modify the database:

If you want to un-attach the featured images, you could use for example (untested):

```
/**
 * Un-attach all featured images:
 */
 $pids = get_posts( 
     array( 
        'post_type'       => array( 'post', 'page' ),
        'meta_key'        => '_thumbnail_id', 
         'fields'         => 'ids',
         'posts_per_page' => 10 // modify this to your needs  
     ) 
 );

 foreach( $pids as $pid )
 {
     // Delete:
     // delete_post_meta( $pid, '_thumbnail_id' ); 

     // Debug:
     printf( ' pid: %d <br/>', $pid );
 }
```

WARNING: Take a database backup before trying this code snippet.

## Method #3 - hijack a filter:

If we go hunting for usable filters, then we are taken down the following path:

- `has_post_thumbnail()`    calls    `get_post_thumbnail_id()`
- `get_post_thumbnail_id()` calls    `get_post_meta()`
- `get_post_meta()`         calls    `get_metadata('post', ... )`
- `get_metadata()`          contains the `get_{$meta_type}_metadata` filter

So the filter to use is the [`get_post_metadata`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.2/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L448) filter.

To hijack the returning value from the filter, `$check` must fulfill:

```
! is_null( $check ) && false === (bool) $check
```

for `has_post_thumbnail()` to return `false`.

To better understand this criteria, we can make some tests:

```
var_dump( ! is_null( 0     ) && false === (bool) 0      );
var_dump( ! is_null( false ) && false === (bool) false  );
var_dump( ! is_null( null  ) && false === (bool) null   );
```

which give the following output:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

This means we can construct the following code snippet:

```
/**
 * Force has_post_thumbnail() to return false.
 */

! is_admin() && add_filter( 'get_post_metadata', 
    function( $check, $object_id, $meta_key, $single ) 
    {
        // Hijack the meta data for featured images:
        if ( '_thumbnail_id' === $meta_key )
        { 
            $check = 0; // or false
        }

        return $check;
    }
,10, 4 );
```

to force `has_post_thumbnail()` to return false.

You can place this code snippet in the `functions.php` file in your current theme directory or use it in your custom plugin.

ps: it looks like this has been solved few years ago, check for example this [thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-use-the-get_meta_type_metadata-filter).

Comment: Thanks. So there isn't a way to not display already-applied featured images, other than removing them?

Comment: There might be a way with the get_post_metadata filter. See [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.2/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L448) in the source code.

Comment: Ah, my Googling missed that last wordpress.org post you linked to. That seems to do the trick! Many thanks for your efforts. If you want to post that code as a separate answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @PhilGyford that's great, ps: my answer already contains a similar `get_post_metadata` filter example to force the `has_thumbnails()` to return `false` ;-)

Comment: But I didn't really understand how to use your answer, whereas the answer on wordpress.org had a function I could use in my functions.php as is.

Comment: @PhilGyford I made some cosmetic changes that hopefully make it more clear ;-)